# This script grabs an extra row only after a single row

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, range

This script works fine until I get to a row with only 1 line with no rows after it.  it is going through and selecting columns A:D and stops at the next blank row.

This works perfectly until it gets a row that is a single row with an immediate blank row after it. When it hits one of those it for some reason selects the first row of the next section as well.

I'm sure it is to do with the half hazard way I put this together. Any help is appreciated

Here is the code:

```
Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim N As Long
Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
Dim sTo As String
Dim StrBody As String
Dim StrBody2 As String
Dim intCol As Integer

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select

StrBody = "Greetings" & "<br>" & _
          "" & "<br>" & _
          "We are conducting our quarterly access appropriateness audit, as required by SOX. We are required to do a quarterly audit of the associates who have access to the application to verify if the access should be marked as retain or remove. The following associate(s) have access to the SSD application. Please reply to this email, stating whether the below associate(s) should be marked to RETAIN or REMOVE the access." & "<br><br><br>"

StrBody2 = "<font color=""red"" >" & "<br>" & "<b>If no response is received, the access will be removed from the associate(s)</b><br></font>" & _
"<font color=""red"" >" & "<b>***Please reply by end of day Tuesday, 21 2015 ***</b></font><br><br><br>"

StrBody3 = "Thank You" & "<br>" & "Transition Audit" & "<bz><bz><bz>"

Set emailRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E3")

For Each cl In emailRng
    sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
Next

sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next

N = Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
Range("A1:D" & N).Select

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Transition Audits"
    .To = sTo
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "2015 Q3 UA-2 SSD, Response Required: SSD (Sales and Service Delivery) SOX Appropriate Access Audit"
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & StrBody2 & StrBody3
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
rng.Resize(, rng.Columns.Count + 1).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Clear
    DeleteBlankRows
 Loop
End Sub
```

Here is an example of a sheet that would have this issue.

Emp ID  Name    Mgr Email

123413  Test4                   test@email.com 
123413  Test5
123413  Test6

123413  Test7                   test@email.com

123413  Test8                   test@email.com 
123413  Test9
123413  Test10
123413  Test11
123413  Test12
123413  Test13
123413  Test14
123413  Test15

The first chunk would work fine and remove the rows up to the single line. When it highlights that row it would also highlight the row starting with Test8

Comment: I figured out a workaround is to enter a blank character in the A column after each single row but that is not ideal by any means.

Comment: Do you use On Error Resume Next for a specific reason? I believe it'd be easier to debug this if every error that occured at least would be visible.

Comment: How do I set it to report errors?

Comment: See [Try Catch statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it very simply

The line 
N = Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row

Needed to be
N = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

As I include the headers each time this is actually perfect anyway.